# Creation of partial index in MongoDB 3.2 freezes inserts

Tags: mongodb, indexing, background

I try to create a partial index on the collection of size 156 Gb with the following command:

```
db.banners.createIndex({campSubTypeId: 1}, {partialFilterExpression: { campSubTypeId: {$exists: true} }}, {background: true})
```

When the command is issued, inserts do not happen (that I can see in mongostats).

What can be a problem?

System: CentOS6.22, MongoDB 3.2, WiredTiger

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. You have two option.

1) Create index in background. This will take a lot more time but will not block other operations.

> By default, creating an index blocks all other operations on a database. When building an index on a collection, the database that holds the collection is unavailable for read or write operations until the index build completes. Any operation that requires a read or write lock on all databases (e.g. listDatabases) will wait for the foreground index build to complete.

2) Create index during off peak hours or ideally if you have replica set, create index on secondaries first and then on primary after stepping down. MongoDB recommends

> If your collection holds a large amount of data, and your application needs to be able to access the data while building the index, consider building the index in the background, as described in Background Construction. To build indexes on replica sets, see the Build Indexes on Replica Sets section for more information.

Please see [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/) for more information.

Comment: The question is why inspite of specified background true,  inserts are blocked.

Comment: Well, according to MongoDB inserts are not blocked for background index creation. However, your active connection will not return until process is completed. This means, you'll be opening a new connection for insert/updates etc. Please see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/#index-build

Comment: Yes,  according to docs it should not block.  But i see the block.  The question is what can be a reason.

Comment: If you are running command in shell, it will get blocked, I'm not sure what is your case as I don't see this behavior. If you want operation to be smooth, consider building Index on replicates.

Comment: Shell will be blocked according to docs.  But as i noted in the question,  i see no inserts in mongostats after i issue the command in the question from the shell.

Comment: I have a system with about 150 inserts per sec.  After i start building index no more inserts are executed.

Comment: Honestly, I don't have answer as I don't see this behavior. I'll suggest you to create a ticket at lira.mongodb.com or contact their support.

Comment: The docs give an example with sparse index.  But i use partial index.  Can it be a reason?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109995/discussion-between-saleem-and-rlib).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you need to place the `background: true` key in the same section as the `partialFilterExpression` key.

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-creation/):

> You can combine the background option with other options, as in the following:
>
> `db.people.createIndex( { zipcode: 1 }, { background: true, sparse: true } )`

So you would use this command:

```
db.banners.createIndex(
  { campSubTypeId: 1 }, 
  { 
    background: true,
    partialFilterExpression: {
      campSubTypeId: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
)
```